# Canadian eTA on different passport

Tags: visas, canada, australia, dual-nationality

As a dual citizen, if I have a valid eTA that expires in 2019 on my British passport, can I get a new eTA for my Australian passport now instead, as that is what I wish to travel on?

Comment: Nitpicking: the eTA is not a visa.

Comment: Ok. perhaps it is more of a visa waiver but is referred to on the application link as and ETA e-visa. https://etravelcanada.org/entry/apply-form-3/

Comment: It's a Travel Authorization. A permit to fly to Canada. Akin to the ESTA in the US.

Comment: @dda the only reason it's not called a visa is to maintain the pretense of continuing to uphold Canada's visa free agreements. Otherwise there's little practical difference.

Comment: @JonathanReez Nope. An eTA or ESTA aren't necessary if you travel by road. So you can indeed enjoy a visa-free entrance without them... Plus, they are MUCH easier to get than a visa...

Comment: @dda let's discuss this here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119431/in-practice-what-is-the-distinction-between-esta-and-visas

Answer (score 4):

This is enough of an edge case that you're unlikely to find an answer in writing, but **it should be fine**, just disclose your other citizenship truthfully when applying for the new ETA.

I've personally been in the same situation with two concurrent US ESTAs in different passports, and it was fine.   (Obvious caveat: the US is not Canada.)

Comment: Strangely for Canada, as their travel information is usually extremely confusing, I found it in plain English on [www.canada.ca](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html): "An eTA is electronically linked to a traveller’s passport." So each passport requires its own eTA.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, but the OP's question is whether a single person is *allowed* to hold multiple concurrent ETAs.

Comment: No, they're _required_ to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, they're required to hold an ETA *in the passport they want to enter Canada with*, but this implies nothing about whether *multiple concurrent ETAs* are permitted.